# Windows Script to recognize a return message from SQL then countdown the loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm new to the world of coding and I'm teaching myself through Windows Scripts to begin.  I'm currently stuck.

I am using a windows script to drop databases in SQL Express.  However, if the database doesn't drop, I need the response to be recognized by the script so that it can trigger a countdown loop.  Once the loop finishes, I have a message sent to the user that 3 attempts to drop the DB failed.

So, if the DB fails to drop and we receive a response from SQL, I need the script to catch it.

Here is a sample response:
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 1, Server SDFRLPOS003\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
Cannot drop the database 'datastore', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I don't need the script to recognize a SPECIFIC response from SQL, just if it gets ANY response from SQL.

My script is working right up to the response from SQL (purposefully drawn).  I can see the response and then the script terminates.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

---

Based on the sample response above, I've tried using:

```
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="11" set /a loopcount=loopcount-1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" > "0" set /a loopcount=loopcount-1
if "%Msg%"=="3701" set /a loopcount=loopcount-1
```

---

Here is what I have:

```
:SQLDropDBStart 
cls
set loopcount=4

:Loop
echo    Deleting DBName Database...     
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -U XXX -P XXX -Q "drop database DBName"

    <<<I DON"T KNOW WHAT TO PUT RIGHT HERE>>>

if %loopcount%==0 goto unableToDropDB
goto    successfulDBDrop
```

I need the script to attempt to drop the database until the loop finished.  At the end of the loop, it will `goto` a message that the DB couldn't be dropped and provide the next steps to the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
:SQLDropDBStart
cls
set loopcount=4

:Loop
echo    Deleting DBName Database...
sqlcmd -b -S .\SQLEXPRESS -U XXX -P XXX -Q "drop database DBName"

rem Error is not 1 or greater (success).
if not errorlevel 1 goto successfulDBDrop

rem Decrease count.
set /a "loopcount-=1"

rem End loop (fail).
if %loopcount% equ 0 goto unableToDropDB

rem Sleep time.
ping localhost -n 3 >nul

rem Another loop.
goto :loop
```

Uses `if not errorlevel 1`, which not 1 or greater.
Less than 1 causes `goto successfulDBDrop` to happen.

If `errorlevel` is 1 or greater, `loopcount` is
decreased by 1.
`loopcount` is then checked if it is 0, and if so,
the `goto unableToDropDB` happens.

Some sleep time is done using `ping` (or you could alternatively use `timeout`) before doing another loop.

View `if /?` for more information about checking the `errorlevel` number.

I also added `-b` argument as [sqlcmd utility page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017#syntax) states:

> **-b**
>
> Specifies that sqlcmd exits and returns a DOS ERRORLEVEL value when an error occurs. The value that is returned to the DOS ERRORLEVEL variable is 1 when the SQL Server error message has a severity level greater than 10; otherwise, the value returned is 0. If the -V option has been set in addition to -b, sqlcmd will not report an error if the severity level is lower than the values set using -V. Command prompt batch files can test the value of ERRORLEVEL and handle the error appropriately. sqlcmd does not report errors for severity level 10 (informational messages).

Without `-b`, `errorlevel` may not be set.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help.

Unfortunately, I'm still having issues and I cannot get the code to recognize the response from SQL.  I'm still plugging away at it, but continued assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Updated answer with adding `sqlcmd` argument of `-b` so it will set `errorlevel`. Give it a try as the rest of the code I double checked as OK. I also redirected `ping` to `nul` to silence any output from it.